# A question about Empiricism

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Empirical means something that can be verified or derivable. How is empiricism different from science? Does empirical philosophy accept reasonable speculations? On the other hand I know science doesn't accept any speculations. Two main steps for establishing facts in science are:

1. Propose an idea mathematically or verbally
2. Provide experimental results.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by ‘empirical philosophy’? If you mean Empiricism (the view that e.g. John Locke championed), this isn’t philosophy that’s done empirically, but (very, *very* roughly) a philosophical view *about* empirical knowledge.

Comment: yes, empiricism.

Comment: "Human Knowledge its Scope and Limits" by Bertrand Russell is still a great book on this subject, very much worth reading for its method and clarity alone.

Comment: Empiricism depends on sensory data. It does not mean 'something that can be verified'. It data is empirical then it is sensory data and Descartes notes that as such it is hypothetical and not (in a full sense) verifiable. I think maybe it would help if you adjusted the question to reflect the correct usage for 'empiricism'.  We all use our sensory data so in the phrase 'empirical philosophy' the first word seems redundant, or perhaps it would be an alternate name for 'natural science'.  .

Comment: Be careful. Whether or not something can be verified is a complicated question. I suggest reading up on the problem of induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three possible understanding of "empirical philosophy" in your question:

- The philosophy of nature, which is just the name given to science before
- Empiricism, which is not a philosophy based on experience, but a doctrine about how knowledge about the world is acquired or justified
- Experimental philosophy, which is a recent approach that aims at questioning folk intuitions to inform various metaphysical questions.

Concerning the first, indeed, empirical philosophy of nature is just science, but your contention that "science doesn't accept any speculation" is false. No scientific theory is content with recording empirical observations: rather it provides a unificatory scheme to unify these observations, and this is a speculative component. It is now generally accepted that the core of a scientific theory is never directly confronted to experience, and that in principle, it is always possible to maintain this core in front of contradictory observations or discrepancies by adding auxiliary hypotheses (and this is very common in science, although generally, one would expect that these new hypotheses are tested by further experiments). You can read Kuhn, Quine or Lakatos on this.

Concerning the second, empiricism is not an empirical hypothesis in the same way scientific hypothesis are, but a meta-hypothesis about how (scientific) hypothesis can be justified, that is, an epistemology, so there's no question of whether it's different from science because it does not pretend to be empirical itself. However some view this as an inherent self-contradiction: how could we know that empiricism is true if it is not itself testable? To this, Carnap and later van Fraassen answer that empiricism should be considered a stance rather than a real hypothesis, and that it should be judged on pragmatist grounds (this is a fruitful or useful stance, it is a good way to extend our knowledge to adopt it, etc). More radically, Quine suggested that epistemology could be just a "chapter of psychology": the idea is that philosophy and science form a web and cannot really be distinguished, so that science informs us on how we acquire knowledge and what we experience. This has come to be called naturalised epistemology. Only in this radical reading is empiricism just science, but even though philosophers accept that science is informative on epistemological issues, few go as far as Quine.

Concerning the third one, the idea of experimental philosophy is that when it comes to questions about the meaning of concepts involved in metaphysics (for example, what free will is, or moral issues), one should question folk usage to have an answer. There are indeed debates on whether experimental philosophy is just psychology rather than philosophy and on whether the whole approach is relevant. You can read the SEP entry on experimental moral philosophy for more information, in particular this section: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/experimental-moral/#WhaCouExpOppPsy

So in sum, when it comes to philosophical views on nature, indeed, empirical philosophy is just science. When it comes to philosophical views on knowledge, it is "meta-science" (epistemology) rather than science and it is usually considered distinct from science, but it's not really empirical. And when it comes to views on other conceptual or metaphysical issues (moral etc) then there's controversy on whether empirical approaches are just science or not.